# Explicit error bounds for orthogonal polynomials with exponential weights

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics, orthogonal-polynomials

Let $\rho > -1$, and define the weight function $W_{\rho}(x) = |x|^{\rho} \exp(-2|x|)$. Associated with this weight is the sequence of orthogonal polynomials $\{ p_{n}(x) \}_{0}^{\infty}$, where $p_{n}(x) = \gamma_{n} x^{n} + \cdots$ has degree $n$ with $\gamma_{n} > 0$, and
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p_{n}(x) p_{m}(x) W_{\rho}(x) \mathrm{d} x = \delta_{nm}.$$
These orthogonal polynomials satisfy the three-term recurrence relation
$$x p_{n}(x) = A_{n+1} p_{n+1}(x) + A_{n} p_{n-1}(x),$$
where $A_{n} = \gamma_{n-1} / \gamma_{n}$.

I am interested in the asymptotics of the recurrence coefficients $A_{n}$ as $n \to \infty$. [Freud's conjecture](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02075448) specialized to the present case shows that to leading order $A_{n}$ scales linearly:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{-1} A_{n} = \dfrac{\pi}{4}.$$
**Question:** what is the subleading correction to this asymptotic scaling?

Detailed error bounds are known for the case where the exponent of the exponential is an even-order polynomial (see [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00365-005-0611-z)), or when the polynomials are defined on the half-infinite line since then you just get the generalized Laguerre polynomials. [This](https://doi.org/10.1155/S1073792899000161) paper gives results for the case $\rho = 0$, but I am interested in how the subleading corrections depend on $\rho$.